# phalcon data insertion not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, debugging, phalcon

I am using phalcon framework for a project.I am trying to insert data to a table.But it is not working and also not showing any error.Here is my code example..

```
$tableData = array(                
                'field1' => 'field1',                
                'field2' => 'field2',  
                'field3' => 'field3',  
                'field4' => 'field4',  
                'field5' => 'field5'

            );
$table= new Table();
$table->save($tableData);
```

I have used wrong field name to see the error of query.But it is not any error or any message and also not inserting data to the database.

Please help me to find out the problem..

Thanks

Comment: If not null validation is not the answer, please show us your table definition.

Comment: not null validation worked for me..thanks for your time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most probably you are facing not null validation error
add this code index.php

```
 \Phalcon\Mvc\Model::setup([
        'notNullValidations' => false
    ]);
```

then you will find the error.and solve it. 
Thanks